How to send custom event to Firebase Analytics with EVENT PARAMETER KEY directly
I am using following code in Kotlin for Android App to send custom events, but these are stored under value Key, but how can I set it directly to EVENT PARAMETER KEY  in Analytics reports, when viewing in dashboard.
Firebase.analytics.logEvent(name, Bundle().apply {
  putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, value)
})

Tried everything but can't find solution to do this.
